# C/C++ Command Parser and Tokenizer

Tags: c++, c

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what this is exactly asking me. Can someone explain this to me? I'm new to Unix and I'm having trouble using my terminal and compiling my code.

The question is asking me to design and implement a C/C++ program that should parse the command from user.

1. One command with arguments and options.
           For example, ls –la  ./cs3000
               Command: ls
               Options: -la
               Arguments: ./cs3000